# Accessing component state from the outside without breaking modularity

Tags: reactjs

Say I have a component like this

```
function SomeComponent(props) {
  const [x, setX] = useState([]);
  const [y, setY] = useState([]);

  return <></>
}
```

Is there a way to access x and y in a sibling component without breaking modularity? By "sibling" I mean a component that's not a child, parent, or grandparent etc.

In other words, I want to access x and y:

- without creating a global state
- without using context
- without storing the state in another component, and passing in setX and setY as props

Comment: If we have this function, it will be disastrous, because when we need to know a state, we need to look for it from the whole application, not just from its parent component

Answer (score 0):

You can't access components state from a different component - It is not accessible to any component other than the one that owns and sets it:

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down